# LVM logical volumes do not activate on boot on 13.10

Tags: encryption, lvm, udev

I am running an UbuntuGNOME 13.10 and I set it up without an LVM during the installation process. I am now running it with to encrypted partitions, one is containing a LVM. This all works fine, except, that the logical volumes are not activated during startup. So I have to enter `vgchange -a y` after unlocking the encrypted partitions.

What I tried so far:

Since `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules` did not exist I tried:

```
# cp /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

As suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1564411.html). But this did not solve my problem.

I also tried to leave out `'ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="lvm*|LVM*"'` in 85-lvm2.rules and installed watershed without success.

What might be connected:
While I am entering my password to unlock the encrypted hard drive my computer tells me that is not able to mount the /var (one of the logical volumes in the LVM)

**Update:** 
This seems to be a problem in Ubuntu, I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130232) and multiple bug reports concerning this
jitos